# MvcHtmlString.Create() method does not return Html encoded string

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I must be missing something here, because [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.create?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_MvcHtmlString_Create_System_String_)

says, `MvcHtmlString.Create("someStringHere")` returns html encoded string, but if i have something like `MvcHtmlString.Create("<h1>myHeading</h1>")` it still shows up as

## myHeading

(as heading) and not as encoded text `&lt;h1&gt;myHeading&lt;/h1&gt;`

Then what is meant by the statement

> MvcHtmlString.Create(String)
>   Creates an HTML-encoded string using the specified text value.

I am not able to understand, would be grateful if somebody could explain what does the doc mean and what's the difference between the encoding they are trying to refer to vs html encoding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could use `@Html.Encode(<MyHtmlStringHere>)` instead.

Comment: @vikscool ,that's correct but my question was not to somehow solve my problem but to understand the use of MvcHtmlString and advantages this provides, and to point out that doc is mis-leading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that the documentation seems misleading for `MvcHtmlString`.

However, `MvcHtmlString` is intended to be used when you *don't* want a string to be HTML encoded. The default behaviour of razor is to encode the output.

The Html string that you pass to it should already be encoded to ensure that it is outputted without additional encoding.

So assuming the following HTML helper:

```
public static class HtmlHelper
{     
    public static string GetHtmlString(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return "<h1>myHeading</h1>";
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString GetMvcHtmlString(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<h1>myHeading</h1>");
    }
}
```

With the Razor view:

```
@Html.GetHtmlString()
@Html.GetMvcHtmlString()
```

The output would be:

`&lt;h1&gt;myHeading&lt;/h1&gt`

## myHeading

Comment: Yes, that's what.., it is totally mis-leading, I got so confused, got to understand this only after implementing myself. I don't know how can I get that doc updated to prevent others from getting this wrong information.

Comment: At the top of each of the documentation pages is an edit button. You could submit a pull request to the team at Microsoft with edits to the documentation :).

Comment: Oh..that's great!! didn't know of it.

Comment: Glad to have helped